# Pass tokens (strings, numbers, etc) from HTML (support file) to LogiXML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html

I am trying to pass a certain parameter (a string in this case) from an external HTML file that I have created and I am trying to pass the selection parameter onto logixml.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could please someone create a "LogiXML" tag, there isn't one and that would be the main category my question would fall upon but I cannot create it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any external parameters passed from HTML  variables can accessed from the POST or GET as a standard @Request token in your Logi definition.

So, for example, passing a parameter in the query string, like this :

```
http://your_server/report_app/rdPage.aspx?myParameter=string
```

Would be accessible in the Logi definition as @Request.myParameter~ where the value equals "string".

If you POST the parameter using a FORM you would access it the same way, @Request.your_form_variable~

Comment: Thank you! Perfect as always! Thanks.